# Is there a way of destructuring an object with the unused as a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, destructuring, spread

So basically, can the unused part of the destructured object be condensed into a variable?

This obviously won't work because "toss" is already declared,

**THIS IS JUST TO ILLUSTRATE THE QUESTION**

```
const obj = { a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4 }
const toss = {b,c};
const {...toss, ...keep} = obj;
console.log(keep);  // { a:1, d:4 }
```

Comment: No. You could write a function that does it though: `function partitionObject(obj, keys) { const a = {}; const b = {}; Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => keys.includes(k) ? a[k] = obj[k] : b[k] = obj[k]); return [a, b]; } const [keep, toss] = partitionObject(obj, ['a', 'd']);`

Comment: `const {b, c, ...keep} = obj;`

Comment: @JaredSmith - I think you're probably the correct with the answer no, there is just no way to declare it,  it's a bummer, it could be so clean & concise.

Comment: `obviously won't work because` because an error will be thrown since b and c are undeclared variables

Comment: You are not _destructuring_ here in that you are not trying to declare any variables called `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d`.  To do what you want by committing to the technique of destructuring constitutes an XY problem.  You're just trying to create an object with certain properties removed.  It's also unclear if you're trying to "keep" the `toss` object (you didn't log it, so I'm assuming you don't want it).

Answer (score 2):

If `toss` is meant to be a list of keys to ignore - then you can define it as an array of strings - rather than the invalid way you defined it that would throw an error

Then it's a simple one liner (there's probably other ways to do this, as there always is in javascript, this is the first that came to mind though)

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }
const toss = ['b', 'c'];
const keep = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([k]) => !toss.includes(k)))
console.log(keep);
```

however, even simpler, since your code is all hard coded anyway

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }
const {b, c, ...keep} = obj;
console.log(keep);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
const _0 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4};
const _1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4};
const _2 = function(_0, _1) {
    let _2 = Object.keys(_0);
    let _3 = _2.length;
    let _4 = '';
    let _5 = {};
    let _6 = 0;

    while (_6 !== _3) {
        _4 = _2[_6++];

        if (typeof _1[_4] === 'undefined' || _0[_4] !== _1[_4]) {
            _5[_4] = _0[_4];
        }
    }

    return _5;
};
const _3 = _2(_0, _1);
console.log(_3);
```

This allows destructuring with `{'key': value}` pair comparisons instead of an array of keys.

A `while()` loop with `Object.keys()` is also faster and more browser-compatible than `Object.entries()`.

Comment: You can explain your answer by adding some description. Adding just a piece of code as an answer is not good.

Comment: I added a brief explanation.

Comment: what language did you originally write this code in? it's practically unreadable with those stupid variable names - I can't for the life of me figure out WHY the code outputs only c and d - it seems like the result is properties of `_0` that don't equal properties of `_1` ... which is absolutely not what the question asked

Comment: `A while() loop with Object.keys() is also faster` not in my browser

Comment: `what language did you originally write this code in?` It's written in JavaScript.

Comment: `it's practically unreadable with those stupid variable names - I can't for the life of me figure out WHY the code outputs only c and d` The answer says it uses comparisons of both the key and value instead of just the key.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why I have an answer ban after 3 correct, useful answers.